# how to count how many times a number occurs in a repeating combination of various length?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, counting

Suppose there are n numbers{1,2,3} and length is k = 2.
Then there are n^k repeating combination.In this case 3^2 = 9 and they are
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),
(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)

Each number occurs 6 times.... i would like to know if I vary the length k then how many times these number will occur ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since every number occurs the same number of times, and the output contains `n^k * k` numbers, every number occur `n^k * k / n` times. In the case `n = 3` and `k = 2`, it is indeed `3^2 * 2 / 3 = 6`.